# Round decimal number in tuple Python

Tags: python

Say I have the following variable

```
var = [('tiktok', 0.4125749944943275),
       ('tiktokers', 0.4125749944943275),
       ('bytedance', 0.2047896978823389),
       ('company', 0.20463320041549565)]
```

How can I convert get the same list of tuples returned but with numbers rounded to 4 decimal points?

Comment: `new_var = [(name, round(val, 4)) for name, val in var]`

Comment: Tuples are immuteable - you need to create new ones. Using `round(number,4)` and a list comp seems viable.